# Blazor pages in multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I have 3 projects 
Projection.Server - this contains the host file and startups
Projection.Shared - This contains the controllers and pages (class library) 
Components.Shared - This contains all components to be used throughout the projects (class library)

My question is that i have all my pages within Projection.Shared for that project but i want to be able to have a page within Components.Shared for my login page that can be used by multiple projects when this solution expands but when i create a login page within the Components.Shared it is unable to direct to the page and says:

> Sorry, there's nothing at this address.

I assume this is the case because the RouteData inside my App.Razor which is situated within Projection.Shared therefore cant access the pages within Components.Shared, is there a possible way round this?

Answer (score 11):

I figured out the answer, in case anybody else runs into this in the future. 
Adding the below to the `App.Razor` file allows it to look at multiple projects:

```cs
AdditionalAssemblies = "new[] { typeof(Shared.Components.App).Assembly }"
```

Comment: Can you please share what's in your `Shared.Components.App`?

Comment: This is a parameter of the <Router> component for the people trying to figure out where to put this.